# replacing a column's values (if it meets a condition) from another existing column's values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, series

I have a `data frame` that consists of 3 columns:

```
Id, Summary, Description
```

What I am trying to do is if any values in `Description` exactly match this string: "This is an empty description", then replace those contents with those of `Summary`.

For example:

Before:

```
   Id     Summary         Description
0  1      Cool song       This is an empty description
1  2      It was ok       was ok because needed more melody
2  3      this was sick   This is an empty description
3  4      not a fan       i prefer classical over rock
4  5      alright         This is an empty description
```

After:

```
      Id     Summary         Description
   0  1      Cool song       Cool song
   1  2      It was ok       was ok because needed more melody
   2  3      this was sick   this was sick
   3  4      not a fan       i prefer classical over rock
   4  5      alright         alright
```

The code I have I am using works, but I wonder if there is a better way because I get a warning:

Input:

```
 df.Description = np.where(df.Description == "This is an empty description", df.Summary, df.Description)
```

Output:

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py:3643: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  self[name] = value
```

Comment: I also am wondering why the output for `type(np.where(df.Description == "This is an empty description", df.Summary, df.Description))` is a `numpy.ndarray`, and when I do `type(df)` says its a `pandas.core.frame.DataFrame`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a really common warning when you are chaining multiple indexing operations in `Pandas`. You can read about it in details [here](https://www.dataquest.io/blog/settingwithcopywarning/). If you want to leverage `Pandas` native methods, you can do something like below without getting any errors.

```
import pandas as pd

mask = (df.Description == "This is an empty description")
df.loc[mask, 'Description'] = df.Summary
```